# How to load value from controller to view file in codeigniter ?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass result6 and result7 value from controller to view file using codeigniter.

**Model file:**

```
function provisional_median($arr) {
        $count = count($arr);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
        $array[]=$arr[$i]->breakdown_grants;
        }
        rsort($array); 
        $middle = round(count($array) / 2); 
        if($count % 2) { // odd number, middle is the median
            $median = $array[$middle];
        } 
        else { // even number, calculate avg of 2 medians
            $low = $array[$middle];
            $high = $array[$middle-1];
            $median = (($low+$high)/2);
        }

        return $median;
   }
```

**controller:**

```
$data['result6']=$this->report_model->actual_median($actual_array_data);
    $data['result7']=$this->report_model->provisional_median($provisional_array_data);
```

**view:**

```
         <td style="text-align:center;">
            <span><?php  print_r(result6); ?></span>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <span><?php echo  print_r(result7);  ?></span>
        </td>
```

Comment: which frame work you are using..??

Comment: codeigniter framework

Comment: you missed $ in view, use <?php  print_r($result6); ?> <?php echo  print_r($result7);  ?>

Answer (score 2):

Try to `load the view` with those variables in `controller` like

```
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);   //Its in CodeIgniter
```

Or in some frameworks it would be like

```
$this->loadView('my_view',$data);
```

And in your view it should be like

```
<span><?php print_r($result6);  ?></span>
```

You are missinh `$` and dont echo the print.

Comment: $this->load->view('reports/take_reports', $data);  i have loaded

Comment: I already told that see my edit...what is the need of Down if its right

Comment: s i did what you said i got the value. but this error indicate in view file  Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: $array[]= ($result[$i]->breakdown_grants + $result1[$i]->breakdown_grants)/100;
  $count = count($array);
  rsort($array); 
        $this->middle = round(count($array) / 2); 
        if($count % 2) { // odd number, middle is the median
        $this->median = $array[$this->middle];
       } 
  else { // even number, calculate avg of 2 medians
         $this->low =$array[$this->middle];
         $this->high = $array[$this->middle-1];
         $this->median = (($this->low+$this->high)/2);
        }
 in view file

Comment: the same coding iam using in view file also

Comment: @sangee I think you have to check the $this->middle value and also may be the $array also

Answer (score 1):

in controller do this :

```
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
```

and in view put the **$** sign with your variable names

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
<span><?php  echo $result6; ?></span>
</td>

<td style="text-align:center;">
    <span><?php echo $result7;  ?></span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
$data['result6']=$this->report_model->actual_median($actual_array_data);
$data['result7']=$this->report_model->provisional_median($provisional_array_data);
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
```

Then in your view file add this and check

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
        <span><?php  print_r($result6); ?></span>
    </td>

    <td style="text-align:center;">
        <span><?php  print_r($result7);  ?></span>
    </td>
```